# MarkLogic TDE doesn't support xdmp:uri-content-type or xdmp:uri-format as transformation functions?

Tags: marklogic

I am a little surprised that `xdmp:uri-content-type` and `xdmp:uri-format` are not supported as transformation functions in MarkLogic TDE (template-driven extraction) template.

> [javascript] TDE-EVALFAILED: tde.nodeDataExtract(...) -- Eval for $doc-format='xdmp:uri-content-type($doc-uri)' returns XDMP-UNDFUN: (err:XPST0017) Undefined function xdmp:uri-content-type()

Indeed the two are not listed as acceptable functions in the documentation: https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/guide/app-dev/TDE#id_99178

Just want to confirm if it is the case and also I am curious about the rationale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These functions require access to mimetype settings inside MarkLogic configuration, which is probably the reason why they are unavailable. To get something similar to format based on a node or document at hand, use `xdmp:node-kind` instead. Content-type will need to be calculated upfront unfortunately, during ingest.

HTH!

Comment: Thanks, @grtjn. But xdmp:node-kind returns values such as "document", "object", "element" etc. How to calculate the content-type?

Comment: Correct. Take root node inside document node (`/node()`) to determine format. element, and attribute are xml only, object and array json only, text at root level must mean text, and binary node must be binary document.

Comment: For content-type, calculate during ingest. E.g. enrich your data with the content-type, while inserting it inside MarkLogic to make it part of the data. You could do the same with format, but you can use node-kind for that too..

Comment: Thanks! You are always so helpful!